# How to recreate ephemeral disks?

Tags: openstack

I've deleted `/var/lib/nova/instances/_base/ephemeral*`. Now I can't launch instance with them:

```
2013-05-29 10:28:11 1313 TRACE nova.compute.manager [instance: 00a23134-8d1b-4f58-9a51-5110d201ade5] Stderr: "qemu-img: Could not open '/var/lib/nova/instances/_base/ephemeral_0_20_None': No such file or directory\n"
```

How can I recreate/recover ephemeral disks?

Answer (score 1):

Create disk with `qemu-img`, fix owner with `chown` and make filesystem with `mkfs.ext3` or `mkfs.ext4`:

```
qemu-img create -f raw /var/lib/nova/instances/_base/ephemeral_0_20_None 20G
chown nova:nova /var/lib/nova/instances/_base/ephemeral_0_20_None
mkfs.ext4 -L ephemeral0 -F /var/lib/nova/instances/_base/ephemeral_0_20_None
```

Comment: i checked in the /var/lib/nova/instances/_base, is not there. where is ephemeral disk...